Join two PowerShell Queries into one PSCustomObject Table
I have this PSCustomObject:
$deviceList = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PnPEntity | Select-Object Name, HardwareID
$pnpDevLs = Get-PnpDevice | Select Object Name, InstanceID
# Loop structure injected here:
$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name       = $device.Name
        HardwareID = $device.HardwareID
        InstanceID = $pnpDev.InstanceID
    }
######################

The goal here is to combine the two queries into one table using a looping mechanism of some kind that would allow me to have this information ready.
I should get a united table with the device Friendly Name, HardwareID as an array, and InstanceID.

Get-PnpDevice is a CIM cmdlet mapped to the Win32_PnPEntity class - so you're effectively issuing the same query twice!
$devices = Get-PnpDevice |Select-Object -Property Name, HardwareID, InstanceID


I did not know about this let me test it.

+1 Life saver. I did not know about this. Do you have a documentation I could about for other relationships that the CIM cmdlet has mapped to Win32_PnpEntity?

Get-PnpDevice is a type of runtime-generated command that's defined through CDXML bindings - whenever you come across documentation that refers to cmdletization = the process of generating the cmdlets. The generated wrapper functions usually declare the resulting CIM class(es) as output types, so you could do (Get-Command Get-PnpDevice).OutputType to discover it. Alternatively, pipe the output from Get-PnpDevice to Get-Member - it'll list the type name (including the CIM class name) at the top

I should note that not all CDXML commands represent a direct 1-to-1 mapping with Get-CimInstance <targetClassName> - some of them might do second-level queries or other post-processing correlations - but in the case of Get-PnpDevice it's just a single query layer with very little to no output formatting (none of which you need to care about here)
